# Is it possible to use setBounds in JPanel?

Tags: java

Is it possible to setBounds components in JPanel? I am trying to apply in adding components in JPanel using setBounds but it doesn't appear in the frame.

Comment: So you're using absolute positioning right ?

Comment: I am using jpanel.setLayout(null); is it posible?

Comment: It is absolutely possible to add bounds to component while adding that component in some container. You can use any layout according to your suitability to setBounds to component.

Comment: Oh yes, it's absolute positioning!  (`null` layout). You don't see your elements because you need to set the size of all elements of you're frame.
A better method would be as @Jack said, use a [layout manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)